# MacOS keychain encryption strength

Tags: macos, keychain, encryption

On a Mac not using hard drive encryption, I wonder how difficult would it be for an attacker with physical access to a machine to break into the keychain This [document](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf) answers the question for iOS 10 (the keychain uses AES 128 in Galois/Counter Mode). But I can't find a document for MacOS that’s current in 2017.

What technical implementation is on macOS High Sierra?

Comment: iCloud keychain uses AES 256 ( https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202303 ) and local keychains use Triple DES for passwords and keys in a keychain, but I can't find a valid link to an official document that proves it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That would make sense as AES is much less CPU-hungry than 3DES, which is a very important consideration on iOS, but probably less so on MacOS. Although with the current generation of both hardware, I'm not sure…

Answer (score 2):

Keychain formatted files use PBKDF2-SHA1 3DES to encrypt the key:

> 1. Keychain uses PBKDF2 with salt and pass, using 1000 iteration and an output size of 24 (for the 3DES key)
> 2. Keychain then decrypts the data with 3DES-CBC but only the last block is used
> 3. Keychain checks if the password was valid by doing a padding attack (checking for 4 consecutive `0x04` bytes at the very end)

See [hashcat issue #2457](https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat/issues/2457) for a technical discussion about supporting Keychain password recovery.

A variety of tools exist to work with Keychain files on multiple platforms, so an attacker could [brute force](https://miln.eu/keysafe/recover/) copied files off site.